# Inherit from two polymorphic classes

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, virtual-functions

Given the following code

```
class T {
    public:
        virtual ~T () {}
        virtual void foo () = 0;
};

class U {
    public:
        U() {}
        ~U() {}
        void bar () { std::cout << "bar" << std::endl; }
};

class A : public U, public T {
    public:
        void foo () { std::cout << "foo" << std::endl; }
};

int main () {
    A * a = new A;

    std::vector<U*> u;
    std::vector<T*> t;

    u.push_back(a);

    t.push_back(reinterpret_cast<T*>(u[0]));

    u[0]->bar ();
    t[0]->foo ();

    delete a;
    return 0;
}
```

I get the output I would expect

```
bar
foo
```

However, if I change the definition of `U` to

```
class U {
    public:
        U() {}
        virtual ~U() {}
        virtual void bar () { std::cout << "bar" << std::endl; }
};
```

I still compile fine and without warnings/errors but the output is now

```
bar
bar
```

What is it about the virtual declaration that prevents me from calling into the `foo`?

Comment: reinterpret_cast is the root of all evil. It was created only so that your team leader knows what to grep for in your code to find your errors ;).

Comment: @KornelKisielewicz, That's an awesome quote!

Comment: you can invoke `foo` on any pointer to either a `T` or an `A`. `foo` has nothing to do with `U`. So I don't quite understand your comment about "virtual declarations" in `U`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, there are no *virtual base classes* in your example. Classes that contain virtual functions are called *polymorphic*. (There is such thing as "virtual base classes" in C++ but it has nothing to do with your example.)

Secondly, the behavior of your code does not depend on any virtual declarations. You have deliberately destroyed the integrity of the base pointer by using `reinterpret_cast`. For this reason the behavior of the code is *undefined*.

A direct cast from one base pointer to another (which is what you are trying to do in your code) is called *cross-cast*. The only cast in C++ that can carry out a cross-cast is `dynamic_cast`.

```
t.push_back(dynamic_cast<T *>(u[0]));
```

You can perform an indirect cross-cast without `dynamic_cast`, but for that you have to downcast the pointer to the derived type first (`A *`) using `static_cast` and then upconvert it to another base pointer type

```
t.push_back(static_cast<A *>(u[0])); // upconversion to `T *` is implicit
```

Comment: Updated topic to reflect the polymorphic comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `reinterpret_cast` you loose all guarantees, and anything you do is "undefined behaviour". In this case, I expect the VMT got messed up, or the VPTR overwritten.

As an illustration, when I compile the first code above, I get a segfault on execution on my compiler.

If you really want to "cross-execute" you should derive from a common base class, and inherit that base class by U and T *virtually* ( `: virtual public`), or use `dynamic_cast` instead of `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: Thanks. I didnt know about `virtual public`

Comment: @ezpz - the difference when you inherit virtually, you inherit the same base class, hence forming a `<>` and not a `\/` when having a common base class

Answer (score 0):

Populate `t` just like you did `u`:

```
t.push_back(a);
```

You don't need `reinterpret_cast` because `A` is a `T`.

Comment: I think he explicitly didn't want that.

Comment: In my particular case I dont have access to the original object pushed into the vector, I've only got the object in the vector itself. It's the reason I'm trying to do all that.

Comment: @ezpz, use `dynamic_cast` then, remember however that it can return NULL.

Comment: @KornelKisielewicz, I didn't understand what he was trying to avoid. With that in mind, I think AndreyT is closest to the answer he probably wants.