# pack any data type into vector <uint8_t>

Tags: c++, vector, stdstring

This question resembles

[serialize any data type as vector<uint8_t> - use reinterpret_cast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161342/serialize-any-data-type-as-vectoruint8-t-use-reinterpret-cast)

```
template <typename T>
inline void pack (std::vector< uint8_t >& dst, T& data) {
    uint8_t * src = static_cast < uint8_t* >(static_cast < void * >(&data));
    dst.insert (dst.end (), src, src + sizeof (T));
}
```

to unpack

```
template <typename T>
inline void unpack (vector <uint8_t >& src, int index, T& data) {
    copy (&src[index], &src[index + sizeof (T)], &data);
}
```

I am trying to pack any type of data into a byte array .

q1 :I have existing tedious implementation using uint8_t* , I hope choice of vector is the best.

q2  : I am not able to properly pack std::string with the above function . Please let me know how comfortable the above function in packing all types of data types

Please let me know how to incorprate std::string into the above soluntion i e pack and std::string into vector

Types of Data I want to pack :

all PODs
  std::string
  vector itself..

Outer Problem :

I want to pack  class like these into a byte array

```
class StartPeerSessionRequest : public Request {

public:
    StartPeerSessionRequest();
    virtual ~StartPeerSessionRequest();
    void composeRequestwithHardCodeValues();
    vector<uint8_t> packRequestWithTemplate();

private:
    uint16_t    mProtocolVersion;
    uint16_t    mSessionFlags;
    uint16_t    mMaxResponseLength;
    string      mMake;
    string      mModel;
    string      mSerialNumber;
    uint8_t     mTrackDelay;
    string      mHeadUnitModel;
    string      mCarModelYear;
    string      mVin;
    uint16_t    mVehicleMileage;
    uint8_t     mShoutFormat;
    uint8_t     mNotificationInterval;

};

class Message {

public:
    Message();
    virtual ~Message();
    void composeMessage(vector<uint8_t> data, uint16_t opcode, uint16_t lengthOfData);

    uint16_t packetheader;
    uint16_t length;
    uint16_t request_response_id;
    uint16_t opcode;
    uint16_t checksum;
    vector<uint8_t> data;
}
```

Byte Array Data type i have chosen is vector(uint8_t)

I want to write it to a device file or send over bluetooth network. I dont want to deserialize the same class as it is. I will receive a response which is again a byte array and I need to eventually unpack the response to a another class

Comment: If you're really need to implement portable (over the wire(-less), for different machines) serialization, then have a look into frameworks like [tag:protocol-buffers] or  [tag:boost-serialization].

Comment: The above function is useful only for POD types. If you want to write code to serialize/deserialize std::string, you'll have to actually do it. It's not difficult to do, but the right way to do it depends a lot on your outer problem -- what do you plan to do with these vectors?

Comment: Updated question with outer problem

Answer (score 4):

**tl;dr:** Use serialization library like [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/libs/serialization/) or [Protocol Buffers](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/).

**Ad 1)** Vector is OK. **Edit: but stream would be better.**

**Ad 2)** Well, you can't serialize objects with indirection this way, because you'll only get the pointer to the actual data, not the data itself. And you can only serialize [plain old data](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/PODType) ([standard layout in C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/StandardLayoutType)) objects; or rather is not guaranteed deserializing object that is not plain old data/standard layout will result in working object. `std::string` (nor any other container) is not POD and contains indirection (`std::string` is just a special kind of vector).

There is **no way** to serialize/pack arbitrary non-standard-layout objects to byte array without special support. Either you have to write serialization and deserialization functions for each such type or you have to give up the byte array requirement and use something like [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/libs/any/) to maintain type information and properly call constructors and destructors for you behind the scenes. Note that `boost::any` itself is a non-standard-layout object with indirection.

**Ad edit:**

> I don't want to deserialize the same class as it is.

Yes, you do. At the other end of the connection. So either

1. the other end uses the same structure and you have to write both serialization and deserialization, one will be used at one end and the other at the other end,
2. the other end uses different structure (possibly even in a different language) and you work on both sides, so you have to write a matching serialize and deserialize, or
3. the other end is written by somebody else and you have to write the serialization to use a specific agreed format.

There are thousands of ways to serialize every type. A string can be serialized as length and content or content terminated with designated terminator (usually 0 byte), an integer (and string size is an integer) can be serialized to different fixed number of bytes, in different order (endian), use variable length encoding etc.

And then there are changes. I see you did include a protocol version. But you also have to write the deserialization code to do different things based on the version, which generally means doing it member-by-member anyway (you want to output the same structure independent on version to keep the downstream code sane) etc.

If you don't have a protocol decided, I recommend you look at [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/libs/serialization/) and [Protocol Buffers](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) libraries.

- Boost.Serialization glues well into existing objects, but is specific to C++ and only provides backward compatibility, i.e. if the sender sends version 2 and receiver was not updated, the message won't be understood at all.
- Protocol Buffers requires defining the messages in it's special format and generating the C++ definition from that, but there are generators for most languages and it supports forward compatibility, i.e. if sender sends version 2, the receiver will understand all fields that were already in version 1 and ignore the ones that were not.

If for some reason you can't use them (unless the target is extremely constrained you should be able to; I work on mobile application that uses both Boost and Protobuf and runs on all current major mobile platforms), at least read their technical descriptions and possibly look in the code so you know how to do serialization well.

Comment: thanks for ur help, Please take serialize/deserialize issue out of the way. I jus wanna pack into a byte array. and also unpack another byte array into several data types. Please let me know any generic  readablesolution thanks

Comment: @MarshelAbraham: Just think I used the words "pack"/"unpack" instead of the words "serialize"/"deserialize"; they are synonyms for this purpose.

Comment: Please let me know any solution just to pack string to vector<uint8_t>, passing the cstring version to the above template function will help ? or let me know any other soln thanks

Comment: @MarshelAbraham: I've added long section regarding your edits.

Comment: @MarshelAbraham: On a side note why did you want to take serialize/deserialize issue out of the way? You are doing the most general case of serialize/deserialize, the network transfer between different platforms (judging from the member names, the sender is almost certainly embedded system).